# Alphanumeric and Symbol validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

i want to validate password field for alpahnumeric and should contain atleast one symbol, can anyone help me with the regex javascript validation

Comment: Could you specify what you classify as a `symbol` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:
/[a-zA-Z0-9]/

Comment: What part of that grabs "at least one symbol"?

Comment: all it does is that it requires either of a-z or A-Z or 0-9. He said at least 1, so why should we care if we more than one? and if there aren't any of those characters, the test would fail

Comment: @Parth, validation should be valid only if it contains alphanumeric value and atleast one symbol, if the field contains, alpha-numeric and it does not have symbol, then the validation fails.

Comment: @Abbas what do mean by "a symbol"? if you consider any non-alphanumberic to be a symbol, you can try to remove everything with his code and compare the length to 1